# Object error in developer tools when adding image for slides plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am inserting images through a for loop into a section of html to be displayed on a slider. I am trying to get this to display on my browser, but my developer tools keeps throwing me a weird error. I think I am inserting a character somewhere and the jquery library is not liking it.

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]:eq(0)

Here is my code.

```
var theImgHTML = "<div class='slides_container portfolio-img'>";

for (i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
    theImgHTML += "<img src='images/portfolio/" + imgList[i] + "' alt='Slide " + (i + 1) + "' />";
}

theImgHTML += "</div>";

$("#slides").html(theImgHTML);

$("#slides").slides({
    preload: true,
    preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
    play: 5000,
    pause: 2500,
    hoverPause: true
});​
```

Here is what comes out as a result in the html.

```
<div class="slides_container portfolio-img" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: block; background-image: url(loading.gif); background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;">
    <div class="slides_control" style="position: relative; width: 0px; height: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <img src="images/portfolio/one.jpg?1354641162837" alt="Slide 1" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
        <img src="images/portfolio/two.jpg" alt="Slide 2" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
        <img src="images/portfolio/three.jpg" alt="Slide 3" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: If I take out the $("#slides").html(theImgHTML); it doesn't crash, but it doesn't show the slider.

Comment: The error states: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]:eq(0)` `eq()` is a jQuery function and if it fails you might be providing something to the slider which the plugin can't index. If you can provide a link to the plug-in and **also** a fiddle to replicate the issue that would help.

Comment: so how would I put my variable of theImgHTML into the slides div?

Comment: You might not be providing HTML to the slide plug-in which is valid. You might be missing a class or something. I don't know the inner workings of that plug-in but it is trying to get the elements in the first index using `eq(0)` which fails. So what ever it is basing its selector on i.e: `$(".slide").eq(0)` returns no elements. Have a look at the plug-in documentation or use the non-minified version and debug it.

Comment: Problem end up being is for the plugin to work you have to append the img tags with divs around each of them. Otherwise it will throw you back that error.

Comment: Nice you found the cause and a fix. If you found a solution to your issue you can post an answer to your own question and accept it. It could help other users with a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem end up being was that when adding the variable "theImgHTML" (contains the markup for my images) into the slides, I needed to encompass each image with a div. I was not doing that. According to the slides plugin when having images to display..each div needs to have an encompassing div surround each image.

I tried it without the div's and just had the image by themselves and the plugin did not accept it (thus the error above). Hopefully, this helps someone out in the future.

Here is an example of what will work.

```
<div id="slides">
     <div class="slides_container">
          <div>
             <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
          </div>
          <div>
             <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

For further info go to the link below and go to basic markup.

http://www.slidesjs.com/